# data.table vs. data.frame in nested foreach loop (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, foreach, data.table, nested-loops

I am aiming to improve performance of a nested loop which computes `mutinformation` and `entropy` of all pairwise combinations of columns. Going from a `for` to a `foreach` loop already brought some relief but I'm not happy yet. In a try & error approach I have tested what happens when I use a `data.table` instead of a `data.frame` inside the nested loop and I am surprised by the results.

1. There really seems to be a significant impact of `data.table` (unfortunately in the wrong direction, it makes it slower) but at least I might be on the right track here. Does anyone have an idea how to impact performance in the other direction and/or an explanation why `data.table` makes it slower?
2. The numeric result of the two flavours (`t` vs. `t2`) differs and I have absolutely no idea what is going on. Does anyone have an explanation why the results are not identical?

Below is a self contained example, you probably don't need my funny .libPaths() ;-) On my machine it is 25 vs. 38 seconds for `data.frame` vs. `data.table`, respectively.

Thanks for any thoughts on this!
Mark

```
# ----- import libraries -----
libs <- c( .libPaths(), "C:/Users/her1dr/AppData/Local/TIBCO/Spotfire/114~1.0/Modules/TIBCOE~1.0/library")
.libPaths(new = libs)
library(infotheo)
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(data.table)

# ----- create synthetic data set -----
input <- data.frame(replicate(150,sample(0:100,100,rep=TRUE)))

# ----- set-up cluster for parallel processing -----
ncl <- max(2,floor(detectCores()*0.75))
clst <- makePSOCKcluster(ncl)
e <- new.env()
e$libs <- .libPaths()
clusterExport(clst, "libs", envir=e)
clusterEvalQ(clst, .libPaths(libs))
clusterEvalQ(clst, { #export required packages to all cores
    library(infotheo)
    library(data.table)
})
registerDoParallel(cl = clst) #register cluster


# ----- computed pairwise complete mutual information -----
x <- discretize(input, disc="equalwidth", nbins=20) #discretized version of the input data
y <- as.data.table(x) # copy of data.frame x as data.table

    # -- using data.frame --
    start_time <- Sys.time()
    t <- foreach (j=1:ncol(x), .combine="c") %:% #parallellized nested loop for computing normalized pairwise complete MI between all columns
            foreach (i=j:ncol(x), .combine="c", .packages="infotheo") %dopar% {
                compl_cases <- complete.cases(x[,c(i,j)])
                if (sum(compl_cases) > 0) {
                    2*(natstobits(mutinformation(x[compl_cases,][,j], x[compl_cases,][,i], method="emp"))/(natstobits(entropy(x[compl_cases,][,j]))+natstobits(entropy(x[compl_cases,][,i]))))
                } else {
                    0
                }
            }
    end_time <- Sys.time()
    print(end_time-start_time)
    
    # -- using data.table --
    start_time <- Sys.time()
    t2 <- foreach (j=1:ncol(y), .combine="c") %:% #parallellized nested loop for computing normalized pairwise complete MI between all columns
            foreach (i=j:ncol(y), .combine="c", .packages="infotheo") %dopar% {
                compl_cases <- complete.cases(y[,.SD, .SDcols=c(i,j)])
                if (sum(compl_cases) > 0) {
                    2*(natstobits(mutinformation(y[compl_cases,.SD, .SDcols=j], y[compl_cases,,.SD, .SDcols=i], method="emp"))/(natstobits(entropy(y[compl_cases,.SD, .SDcols=j]))+natstobits(entropy(y[compl_cases,.SD, .SDcols=i]))))
                } else {
                    0
                }
            }
    end_time <- Sys.time()
    print(end_time-start_time)
    
stopCluster(cl=clst) #stop cluster

all.equal(t,t2)
```

Comment: `data.table` already uses threads. I'd run it without foreach, although I don't know how it handles the double parallelization.

Comment: `y[[j]][complete_cases]` should work?

Comment: Thanks for your coments! @MichaelChirico, are you proposing to use `y[[j]][complete_cases]` instead of `y[compl_cases,.SD, .SDcols=j]` and similarly for `i`? Would you expect a significant impact on peformance or is this more about cleaner code? @Andre Wildberg, are you proposing a nested `for` loop combined with `data.table`? BTW, just included as.matrix as a third flavour, outperforms data.table and data.frame big time for larger data sets and the resulting data is identical to the one from data.frame!

Comment: yes, a significant impact. `[` has some overhead that can be nontrivial in "raw" use cases like yours where you want to run `[` many times and there are simple alternatives.